# Function returning double when expected long

Tags: c++, c++14, functor

I recently answered another question and in my answer I had the following code.

```
template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct are_arithmetic{
    enum {
        value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && are_arithmetic<Ts...>::value
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct are_arithmetic<T>{
    enum {
        value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value
    };
};

template<typename Arg, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<Arg>::value>>
Arg max(Arg arg){
    return arg;
}

template<typename Arg, typename Arg1, typename ... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<are_arithmetic<Arg, Arg1, Args...>::value>>
auto max(Arg arg, Arg1 arg1, Args ... args){
    auto max_rest = max(arg1, args...);
    return arg > max_rest ? arg : max_rest;
}
```

Now, from this code I assumed that `max()` would return the maximum number from a given list of numbers as well as retaining its type.

But when the original poster tried the code:

```
int main(){
    auto res = max(1.0, 2, 3.0f, 5, 7l);
    std::cout << typeid(res).name() << " "  << typeid(7l).name();
}
```

He got `d l` from stdout.

This shows that the return type of the function isn't what expected at all. Why does the function not return a `long`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that when the `max`() function is called as:

```
auto res = max(1.0, 2, 3.0f, 5, 7l);
```

Then given its signature:

```
auto max(Arg arg, Arg1 arg1, Args ... args){
    auto max_rest = max(arg1, args...);
    return arg > max_rest ? arg : max_rest;
}
```

Here, `Arg` would obviously be a `double`.

Then return value is a ternary operator:

```
return 1.0 > max_rest ? 1.0 : max_rest;
```

It's not important what `max_rest` winds out to be. Let's say it's indeed, a `long`. So you have a ternary operator, with one `double` expression, and one `long` expression.

Seems to me that the `long` expression is going to be type-promoted to a `double`, so the return `auto` type is a `double`.

Comment: How is a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Define 'circumvent'. It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve here. Given how you defined max() the end result would always be type-promoted to the widest of its arguments. That is, indeed, the correct thing to do. Here, your arguments are a double, an int, a float, and int, and a long. The whole max() function ends up recursively expanded to one huge, nested, ternary operator. So, your result will always be the widest type of its parameters. If you want to explicitly cast the result to a long, how are you going to know that the actual max isn't a fractional double?

Comment: I mean, how could I define this function in such a manner that no type promotion will occur. I don't have to use a ternary operator, that's just how I did it in the first place.

Comment: This is only possible if all arguments to your max() are constant. If they aren't, this is not possible, of course. If they are, a solution is possible using specialization. So your max() will read something like this: return max_value<arg, max(arg1, args...)>::value() then define a max_value template class taking two opaque values as template parameters, default the third parameter to is_less=value1 < value2, then specialize two versions, with the third parameter being true or false, each specialization defining value() as returning the appropriate value.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, if there is to be "no type promotion", you still have to define what type you expect the output to be. If not the widest of the arguments, what do you want? The narrowest type? So that `max(3.14,2)` would be `3`?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Your function has to have a return type. That return type has to be determined at compile time, not run time.

Comment: ... unless you mean that the type should be the type of the largest value? That's going to be impossible (unless you know all the values at compile time) but it could be useful if you could clarify that that is what you want

Comment: @AaronMcDaid that is what the question says. `return the maximum number from a given list of numbers as well as retaining its type`

Comment: I do understand now that it has a runtime dependency, so the widest type has to be used.

Comment: Aha. Sorry I missed that. That's impossible, as others will explain in their answers. If you used only integral types, and if you knew the values at compile time, then you could hack together something. But I guess that's not good enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of

```
template<typename Arg, typename Arg1, typename ... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<are_arithmetic<Arg, Arg1, Args...>::value>>
auto max(Arg arg, Arg1 arg1, Args ... args){
    auto max_rest = max(arg1, args...);
    return arg > max_rest ? arg : max_rest;
}
```

doesn't depend of value, but of given type.
So here it returns the common type of all args.